# Call PHP page via jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I have a PHP page and inside that PHP page I just have `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>` and I want to use JavaScript (preferabbly jQuery) and AJAX to CALL that php page and return it's output (which would be "Hello World!")

How is this done?

Comment: So many duplicates... did you even try searching for a solution first?

Comment: That should be enough for this question http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: None suited you? I'm not sure I understand what you mean..

Comment: Damn, I was such an idiot back then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `data` will contain the text from the page, do what you want with it. In this case, set the `#responseArea` text to contain it.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "yourPage.php",
   success: function(data){
     $("#responseArea").text(data);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 10):

Pretty basic.

[jQuery.ajax() – jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You'll find lots of examples near the bottom.