# fetch data from db depending on what user select

Tags: javascript, php, html

im a newbie to Backend and PHP. Im trying to fetch data from my database to an Input field depending on what user chooses from the dropdown menu. I have values in the dropdown menu that i fetch from the DB. If the user clicks an element in the dropdown list, its data from the DB should be displayed in the input field.
Another question, should i write a new php page for this? or can this happen at the same html page?.
a small code example would help a lot, thanks :)

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">value 1 from db </a>
    <a href="#">value 2 from db</a>
    <a href="#">value 3 from db</a>
  </div>
</div>

<form name="f" action="" method="">
  <div class="main">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 0;"> Name </td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 0;"> <input type="text" name="Name" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 0;"> Adress </td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 0;"> <input type="text" name="Adress" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 0;"> ZIP </td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 0;"> <input type="text" name="ZIP" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

the style sheet code

```
/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

and a small javascript code for the dropdown menu

```
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  });
}
```

here is a live demo of the working code

https://jsfiddle.net/m4sxnzg0/1/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Study some tutorials on using ajax and php.

Comment: @charlietfl cant this be done just using PHP ?

Comment: Yes it could if you want to reload page. Use a query string in href url and read that $_GET value to fill the inputs server side

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Ajax(which i suggest) you can find out how, via this post: [Call PHP page via jQuery/Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680343/call-php-page-via-jquery-ajax)

If you're looking to only use PHP, you can reload the page, and variables to the URL and retrieve them in PHP with $_GET.

Find more info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php